# Using BETWEEN operator in CASE (THEN) statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying the following but its throwing an error, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT custType, count(*)
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbID = b.tbID
AND ((CustType IN ('Apple','IPAD') and  date BETWEEN @StartDate   AND @EndDate)
or (CustType IN ('Samsung','LCD') and date BETWEEN @StartDateLL AND @EndDateLL))
GROUP BY CustType
```

Comment: what is the table of `date` and `custType` fields?

Comment: Tip: Keeping the error message text a secret doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't use `AND/OR`

```
    SELECT CustType , count(*)
    FROM tbl1 a
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbID = b.tbID
    AND ((CustType IN ('Apple','IPAD') and  date BETWEEN @StartDate   AND @EndDate)
      or (CustType IN ('Samsung','LCD') and date BETWEEN @StartDateLL AND @EndDateLL))
    group by CustType ;
```

**EDIT** You can't group by CustType and Select *

Comment: ya i guess i could do that. I have a group by clause right after (forgot to add) but its now giving me an error on the group clause (incorrect syntax)

Comment: @Faiz note because it could be a simple answer, the ";" semi colon in vercelli's answer needs to be removed if you are adding further sql statements.after the join condition

Comment: I removed the semi colon its still giving the error of incorrect syntax near keywork group

Comment: @all I have sorted it. LOL I had an extra bracket at the wrong place. THanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a BETWEEN operator for the THEN part of a case statement or IIF.  `BETWEEN` is the condition that translates to true and false.  So it is `VALUE BETWEEN A AND B` and would be apart of the WHEN section of a case statement.

Also the case statement returns a value not a formula to be further executed.

I agree with @Vercelli's solution but to show you how a case statement works in the method you are trying you could do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbID = b.tbID
AND (CASE
WHEN CustType IN ('Apple','IPAD') AND [date] ETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN 1
WHEN CustType IN ('Samsung','LCD') AND [date] BETWEEN @StartDateLL AND @EndDateLL THEN 1
ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Again go with @vercelli's answer as it is the more appropriate way of writing the SQL query.